# How to convert Date/time from the character string

Tags: sql-server

How to convert Date/time from the character string

```
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RegistrationCreatedDate, 10) AS 'Date Submitted'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StatusUpdatedDate, 10) AS 'Current Status Date'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, [AcceptedDate])), 10) AS 'Date Accepted'
    , PaymentAuthID
    , PaymentAmount
FROM (
    SELECT R.RegistrationGUID
        ,CAST(RR.ShortResponseValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ResponseValue
        ,RR.QuestionShortCode
        ,R.ApplicationGUID
        ,R.RegistrationUpdatedDate
        ,XRSH.StatusUpdatedDate
        ,OD.ResponseValue AS PaymentAuthID
        ,CD.ResponseValue AS PaymentAmount
        ,APS.STATUSNAME
        ,O.OrderGUID
        ,[RegistrationCreatedDate]
```

I have an error on this line:
`,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, [AcceptedDate])), 10) AS 'Date Accepted'`
The error is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Often depends on what your character string looks like.  Please supply a sample

Comment: Your example works somehow. Specify what you whant to get and what you get now

Comment: I am having error on this line  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, [AcceptedDate])), 10) AS 'Date Accepted'. the error is Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: If you run query 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, GETDATE())), 10) AS 'Date Accepted'
it will be fine. So, there's something wrong with data in [AcceptedDate] column. Could you show some examples of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, [NameColumn])), 10) AS 'Date Accepted'
FROM [NameTable]
```